# How i can tap the inner part(link) of the textview using appium for both android and ios?

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLAIg.png)>am using java client, i have text-view with links and text i need to click on the link.

**i found some solutions with finding coords and tap on the location, but when you move on to different size mobile it might differ.**

we usually used tap elements using below code:

> for android,

```
GlobalVariables.android_driver.findElement(By.id(tappable_element)).click();
```

> for IOs

```
GlobalVariables.ios_driver.findElement(By.id(tappable_element)).click();
```

> thanks in advance

Comment: where is that link, is it in UI or in your code redirecting ?

Comment: its in UI textview, find image on top

Comment: img link on top